# npm bin property is not working as expected

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-interface

I wrote a simple 'addheader' node module and published it on npm. It contains a cli script which I registered in the package.json config-file in the bin property as follows:

```
{ 
   "name" : "addheader", 
   "bin" : "./addHeaderCli.js" 
}
```

Installing the module with "npm install addheader" I can see the cli script in the node_modules folder as follows:

```
node_modules/.bin/addheader
```

Unfortunately I can't use the cli as expected. When run it like this:

```
node addheader 'test.txt' 'A header'
```

It always fails with the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/sepp/camp/npmbuild/addheader'
 at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
 at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
 at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
 at startup (node
```

Run it providing the path works fine:

```
./node_modules/.bin/addheader 'test.txt' 'A header'
```

I've consulted the npm [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) but I couldn't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

By the way I'm running node version 0.12.4 on a mac.

you can find the module on npmjs https://www.npmjs.com/package/addheader

Comment: I solved the problem by adding the following line to the top of the cli file: `code`#! /usr/bin/env node. Now I can cal it like: `code`addheader 'test.txt' 'my header'`code`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding the following line to the top of the addHeaderCli.js:

```
#! /usr/bin/env node
```

Now I can cal it like:

```
addheader 'test.txt' 'my header'
```

Comment: I don' think this is the proper way of doing that.  NPM will do that logic for you if you have it under bin, it will also take account for Windows as well.  Your problem is that you calling node before your addheader.

Comment: I can call it now without 'node'. Thanks for the hint, I'll change the call in the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a bin you should not be invoking it with `node` it it just a standalone binary.

karma

> Command not specified. Karma - Spectacular Test Runner for JavaScript.

node karma

> module.js:338
>       throw err;
>             Error: Cannot find module